# Riesz representation (Royden, 4ed)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, riesz-representation-theorem

I'm reading Royden's Real Analysis 4ed, and have doubts about the proof of Theorem 5 in Section 8.1.

The theorem says: if $T$ is a bounded functional on $L^p[a, b]$, then there is a function $g \in L^q[a, b]$, where $q$ is the conjugate of $p$, for which $T(f) = \int_a^b g \cdot f$, $\forall f \in L^p[a, b]$.

The proof constructs such a function $g$, and then shows $T(f) = \int_a^b g \cdot f$, for all step functions in $L^p[a, b]$. Then it proceeds to show $T(f) = \int_a^b g \cdot f$, for all simple functions in $L^p[a, b]$. Finally, it shows the functional $S(f) = \int_a^b g \cdot f$, for **all fucntions** in $L^p[a, b]$, and then applies a previous proposition: since $T=S$ on all simple functions, and the space of simple functions is dense in $L^p[a, b]$. Therefore, $T=S$ in $L^p[a, b]$.

My question is: the space of step functions is also dense in $L^p[a, b]$(Proposition 10, Section 7.4), why bother proving $T(f) = \int_a^b g \cdot f$ for all simple functions? Can't we say, since $T=S$ on all step functions, and the space of step functions is dense in $L^p[a, b]$, hence $T=S$ on $L^p(E)$?

Comment: You need some information about the function $g$ in order to conclude that the extension of the functional retains the integral representation, even though it is obvious that the functional value for a general $f\in L^p$ is obtained uniquely through $L^p$ limits of simple functions.

Comment: Thanks, I get it. In order for $g \in L^q[a, b]$, the inequality $|\int_a^b g \cdot f| \leq M ||f||_p$ must hold for simple functions.